# Kafka message delivery failure

Tags: rubygems, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to use kafka ruby client - https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka for posting logs to kafka. Below are the logs from kafka

```
I, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.131775 #14887]  INFO -- : Fetching cluster metadata from kafka://10.10.10.162:9092
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.131939 #14887] DEBUG -- : Opening connection to 10.40.50.16:9092 with client id ruby-kafka...
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.133199 #14887] DEBUG -- : Sending request 1 to 10.40.50.16:9092
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.133339 #14887] DEBUG -- : Waiting for response 1 from 10.40.50.16:9092
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.134763 #14887] DEBUG -- : Received response 1 from 10.40.50.16:9092
I, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.134823 #14887]  INFO -- : Discovered cluster metadata; nodes: kafka1:9092 (node_id=1), kafka2:9092 (node_id=2), kafka3:9092 (node_id=3)
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.134882 #14887] DEBUG -- : Closing socket to 10.40.50.16:9092
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.135018 #14887] DEBUG -- : Current leader for TRANSACTION_GOCARS/0 is node kafka2:9092 (node_id=2)
I, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.135092 #14887]  INFO -- : Sending 1 messages to kafka2:9092 (node_id=2)
D, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.135195 #14887] DEBUG -- : Opening connection to kafka2:9092 with client id ruby-kafka...
E, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.135750 #14887] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to kafka2:9092: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
E, [2016-08-03T17:54:38.135825 #14887] ERROR -- : Could not connect to broker kafka2:9092 (node_id=2): getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Does any one has any info regarding how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnknownHostException kafka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497279/unknownhostexception-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty informative in your case - `kafka2` is not routable, so you should either configure connectivity so that the machine you are trying to access `kafka2` from is really can reach it or change the `advertised.host.name` in Kafka's `server.properties` to expose a different address for clients

Answer (score 0):

try to ping or curl the `kafka2` broker in ur application, to see whether u can connect to it or not. or can u tell us the `server.properties` about `kafka2`. The host name might not be reachable.